# How do I add all contents of 2 different google drive folders in GmailApp

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, email-attachments

I am trying to add all contents of 2 different folders in google drive to my GmailApp so that email contains all the files from both folders.

Sample Code: it throws an error Exception:

> Invalid argument: attachment at sendEmail(Code:180:20)

```
         var contents = DriveApp.getFolderById('***').getFiles();

         var contentspdf = DriveApp.getFolderById('***').getFiles();
        
            var attach = [];

            while(contents.hasNext()){

                 var file = contents.next();

                 if (file.getMimeType() == "application/pdf"){

                     attach.push(file);

               }
          }
        
          var attachtwo = [];

          while(contentspdf.hasNext()){

              var files = contentspdf.next();

              if (files.getMimeType() == "application/pdf"){

                 attachtwo.push(files);
             
               }
         }

         GmailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, Subject, messageBody,{
         
               attachments: [attach, attachtwo,],

               name: 'Test'
         });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to put all the attachments into the `attachments` argument:

`attachments: [...attach, ...attachtwo]`

---

**Solution:**

```
 var contents = DriveApp.getFolderById('***').getFiles();

 var contentspdf = DriveApp.getFolderById('***').getFiles();

    var attach = [];

    while(contents.hasNext()){

         var file = contents.next();

         if (file.getMimeType() == "application/pdf"){

             attach.push(file);

       }
  }

  var attachtwo = [];

  while(contentspdf.hasNext()){

      var files = contentspdf.next();

      if (files.getMimeType() == "application/pdf"){

         attachtwo.push(files);
     
       }
 }

 GmailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, Subject, messageBody,{
 
       attachments: [...attach, ...attachtwo],

       name: 'Test'
 });
```

---

Please make sure the [V8 Runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime) environment is enabled.